# AngularJS : Not able to call a function in a controller from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have been trying to call a controller function from my directive but I have failed to do so, inside the directive I have tried both one way and two way binding but to no avail, right now in the console logs I can see that actOnMouseEnter function gets called when ng-mouseenter event gets trigerred. When applying breakpoints in the dev tools I see the line *" scope.onMouseEnterNotify({name: scope.name, hoveredEntry:entry});"* gets hit but the function in the contoller never gets called.

Please correct me if I am wrong, since we have created a new scope inside the directive the function that we pass from the html as 'on-mouse-enter-notify='onMouseEnterCallback(name,hoveredEntry)'  is bound to the attribute onMouseEnterNotify in the directive which we could use at a later point when we want to call the function in the controller.

I am new to angular, please help.

**Directive**

```
(function () {

var canvas;
var directiveWithArg = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            componentName: '=',
            componentArgs: '=',
            onMouseEnterNotify: '&',
            onMouseLeave: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'shared/directives/_draw_square_variable_param.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            scope.$watch('[componentName,componentArgs]', function (newValue) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                canvas.id = newValue[0];
                scope.entries = [];
                scope.name = newValue[0];
                scope.entries = newValue[1];
            }, true)

            scope.actOnMouseEnter = function( entry ) {
                console.log( "In side actOnMouseEnter");
                scope.onMouseEnterNotify({name: scope.name, hoveredEntry:entry});
            }

            scope.actOnMouseLeave = function(entry) {
                console.log( "Out of hovering area " + entry );
            }
        }
    };
};

app.directive('squareDrawVariableArgs', directiveWithArg);
```

}());

**Corresponsing HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="canvas" class="panel panel-danger" style="max-width: 150px">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class="panel-title image-holder-heading" style="font-size: 10px" ng-model="name">
                {{name}}
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in entries" style=" color: #CCCCFF"  id={{p}} ng-mouseenter="actOnMouseEnter(p)" ng-mouseleave="actOnMouseLeave(p)" >
                    <td >
                        <span class="label label-info" ng-model="p">{{p + "testing app"}}</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML from which this directive is invoked:**

```
   <div class="row top-buffer">
        <square-draw-variable-args component-name='testName' component-args='myTestArray' ng-model='testName' on-mouse-enter-notify='onMouseEnterCallback(name,hoveredEntry)'></square-draw-variable-args>
    </div>
```

**Corresponding JS**

```
   'use strict';

    app.controller('MddController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $interval, mddErrorPanelFactory) {

        $scope.testName = "Testing the new directive";
        $scope.myTestArray = [1,2,3,4];

   var onMouseEnterCallback = function( name, hoveredEntry ) {
        console.log( " +++ name " + name + " hovered entry " + hoveredEntry );
    }
```

});

Comment: `onMouseEnterCallback` should be exposed on the scope: `$scope.onMouseEnterCallback = function...`

Comment: you should then delete the question